# The Three-machine proportionate flow shop problem with unequal machine

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming

As part of an Academic project I wrote the following code, according to the algorithm (verbal).  When I checked the rest of the article I notice that the efficiency should be \$O(n^2)\$ and I wrote \$O(n)\$.

I know that I didn't finish and that there is much to do.  I'm putting my code and article here and wishing to get some way with that or even an answer.

I've attached a link to the article on my college server (a PDF file only the third page relevant the rest is abstract and reducing): [the article](http://my.jce.ac.il/~eladoz/Dynamic/Dynamic%20Programming%20Algo)

I have a merge-sort object but it irrelevant here as it worked.

**`Job` class:**

```
public class Job{
    private String name;// contain the name of the job(optional)
    private int num;//contain the serial number of the job
    private int duration;// contain the processing time of the job
    private double start;//contain the starting time of the job
    private double end;//contain the ending time of the job


    public Job(){

        this.num = 0;
        this.duration = 0;
        this.start = 0;
        this.end = 0;

    }//end of empty constructor

    public Job(int num, int duration){

        this.num = num;
        this.duration = duration;

    }//end of constructor

    public void setNum(int num){
        this.num = num;
    }//end of setNum method

    public int getNum(){
        return this.num;
    }//end of getNum method

    public void setDuration(int duration){
        this.duration = duration;
    }//end of setDuration method

    public int getDuration(){
        return this.duration;
        }//end of getDuration method

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }//end of setName method

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }//end of getName method

    public void setEnd(double end){
        this.end = end;
    }//end of setEnd method

    public double getEnd(){
        return this.end;
    }//end of setEnd method

    public void setStart(double start){
        this.start = start;
    }//end of setEnd method

    public double getStart(){
        return this.start;
    }//end of setEnd method

    public String toString(){
        String str = "Job number is: " + getNum() + ", " +"and the duriation is: " + getDuration();
        return str;
    }//end of toString method

}//end of class
```

**Main class:**

```
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter;

  public class assemblyLine{

        public static void main(String[]args){
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            double rateTime;
            int numOfJobs;
            Job []job_order;
            MergeSort sorter = new MergeSort();

            //getting input from the user
            do{
            System.out.println("please enter Rate-Time:");
            rateTime = in.nextDouble();
            }while(rateTime <=0 || rateTime >1);
            do{
            System.out.println("Enter how many Jobs do you have: ");
            numOfJobs = in.nextInt();
            }while(numOfJobs <=0);
            System.out.println("Attention!!! Please enter the processing time of all jobs" + "\n" + "Note: please insert the same times unit! ");
            System.out.println();
            job_order = new Job[numOfJobs];//define an array
            //Vector<Job>[][] p_Matrix = new Vector[3][numOfJobs];//define vector matrix
            for(int i=0; i<job_order.length ;i++){
                System.out.println("please enter the processing time of job " +(i+1) +":");
                job_order[i] = new Job((i+1),in.nextInt());
            }//end of input loop

            sorter.sort(job_order);
            job_order = sorter.sendBackSortedArr();
            //don't need to sort anymore! need to release memory for the calculation!!!
            sorter = null;
            System.gc();

            for(int i=0;i<job_order.length;i++){
                System.out.println(job_order[i]);
            }

            if(numOfJobs == 1)
                System.out.println("\n" +"Note: Only One Job!!!" +"\n" + "The Makespan is: " +((job_order[0].getDuration()*2) + (job_order[0].getDuration()/rateTime)) +"[time-units]");
            else{

                Vector<Job> solution =  new Vector<Job>();//this is the vector that will keep the optimum job order of the machines
                solution.add(job_order[0]);//adding the first job
                //double t1end,t2,t2end, makeSpan;
                double t1,t2, makeSpan;
                //in this part we calculate the durations and the start and the end of each machine/job as a preparation for the calculate

                makeSpan = 2*job_order[0].getDuration() + (job_order[0].getDuration()/rateTime);
                t1 = job_order[0].getDuration();
                t2 = t1;

                int switcher=0;

                for(int i=0; i <job_order.length;i++){
                    double rightGap, leftGap, helper =0;

                    if((t1 >= job_order[i].getDuration()) && (t2 >= job_order[i].getDuration())){
                        helper = Math.min(leftGap = makeSpan + job_order[i].getDuration(),rightGap = makeSpan + job_order[i].getDuration());
                        if(leftGap == helper)
                            switcher =1;
                        else if(rightGap == helper)
                            switcher =3;
                    }//end of if condition - first at the function

                    else if((t1 <job_order[i].getDuration()) && (t2 >= job_order[i].getDuration())){
                        helper = Math.min(leftGap = makeSpan + job_order[i].getDuration() + (job_order[i].getDuration()/rateTime) - t1,rightGap = makeSpan + job_order[i].getDuration());
                        if(leftGap == helper)
                            switcher =2;
                        else if(rightGap == helper)
                            switcher =3;
                    }//end of else-if condition - second at the function

                    else if((t1 >= job_order[i].getDuration()) && ((t2) < job_order[i].getDuration())){
                        helper = Math.min(leftGap = makeSpan + job_order[i].getDuration(),rightGap =  makeSpan + job_order[i].getDuration() + (job_order[i].getDuration()/rateTime) -(makeSpan -t2));
                        if(leftGap == helper)
                            switcher =1;
                        else if(rightGap == helper)
                            switcher =4;
                    }//end of else-if condition - third at the function

                    else if((t1 < job_order[i].getDuration()) && (t2 < job_order[i].getDuration())){
                        helper = Math.min(leftGap = makeSpan + job_order[i].getDuration() + (job_order[i].getDuration()/rateTime) - t1 ,rightGap = makeSpan + job_order[i].getDuration() + (job_order[i].getDuration()/rateTime) -t2);
                        if(leftGap == helper)
                            switcher =2;
                        else if(rightGap == helper)
                            switcher =4;
                    }//end of else-if condition - fourth at the function

                    if(switcher ==1){
                        solution.add(0, job_order[i]);
                        makeSpan +=job_order[i].getDuration();
                        t1 = t1 - (job_order[i].getDuration()/rateTime)+ job_order[i].getDuration();
                    }//end of "if" condition by first dot!

                    else if(switcher ==2){
                        solution.add(0, job_order[i]);
                        t1 = job_order[i].getDuration();
                        makeSpan+= (job_order[i].getDuration()/rateTime)+ job_order[i].getDuration() -t1;
                    }//end of "else-if" condition by second dot!

                    else if(switcher ==3){
                        solution.add(job_order[i]);
                        t2 =t2 -(job_order[i].getDuration()/rateTime)+job_order[i].getDuration();
                        makeSpan +=job_order[i].getDuration();
                    }//end of "else-if" condition by third dot!

                    else if(switcher ==4){
                        solution.add(job_order[i]);
                        t2+= job_order[i].getDuration();
                        makeSpan +=(job_order[i].getDuration()/rateTime)+job_order[i].getDuration()-t2;

                    }//end of "else-if" condition by fourth dot!


                }//end of for loop
                System.out.println();
                System.out.print("The Makespan is: "+makeSpan +"[time-units]"+ "\n"+"flow: [");
                for(int i=0; i<solution.size()-1;i++)
                    System.out.print(solution.elementAt(i).getDuration()+",");
                System.out.print(solution.elementAt(solution.size()-1).getDuration()+"]");
                System.out.println(t1);

            }//end of else - more then one job

        }//end of main


        //this method should return a matrix with the job schedule and the processing time of every job at all machine
        public static Job[][] createingP(Vector<Job> solution, int numOfJobs, double rateTime,double t1){
            Job schedule[][] = new Job[3][numOfJobs];

            return schedule;
        }//end of creatingP method
        /*
        public string toString(){
            String str = "\n" + "The Makespan is: "+makeSpan +"[time-units]"+ "\n"+"flow: ["
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("The Makespan is: "+makeSpan +"[time-units]"+ "\n"+"flow: [");
            for(int i=0; i<solution.size()-1;i++)
                System.out.print(solution.elementAt(i).getDuration()+",");
            System.out.print(solution.elementAt(solution.size()-1).getDuration()+"]");
        }//end of toStringmethod
    */

    }//end of class

    /*
    //calculates the new makespans options 
    boolean t1Biggest, t2Biggest;
    double option1 = makeSpan + job_order[i].getDuration();
    double option2 = makeSpan + job_order[i].getDuration() + (job_order[i].getDuration()/rateTime);
    double option3 = makeSpan + job_order[i].getDuration();
    double option4 = makeSpan + job_order[i].getDuration() + (job_order[i].getDuration()/rateTime) - t2;
    */
```

Comment: That link is not working for me (server is taking too long to respond)

Comment: Iv'e checked again and it's work fine for me
if you'll give me an address of any platform I can send it to you directly

Comment: Well, I am not about to suggest you send anything to me, or anyone else, but, [it is not just me that has a problem with it](http://www.isup.me/http://my.jce.ac.il/~eladoz/Dynamic/Dynamic%20Programming%20Algo).

Answer (score 2):

- Don't ever call `System.gc()`.  It probably won't even do anything, and if it does, it will most likely be less efficient than what Java does by default.
- Don't use `Vector`, but `List` instead.  `Vector` has been somewhat deprecated for over a decade.
- Break things down in methods.  A rule of thumb is that a method should not be more 10 lines long.  It's not a rule that I always follow, but your method is much too long.
- Even better than breaking things down in methods, is to break them down by classes (object-oriented programming).  You need to think about what goes on in your code and break things in semi-independent logically-consistent entities.  It is actually not trivial to get this decomposition right, but it comes with experience.  For example, you should define a main class which will take the input parameters as its constructor argument.  Then you have a method that reads the user inputs and instantiate the main object.
- The for-loop with `switcher` is much too long.  You could define one method that takes the parameters `t1, t1, i` and compute the value of `switcher` from those.  Then you can have a method that reads in the `switch` value and modifies the member values of your object accordingly.  (I'm not sure what exactly the object should be, but you can think about that.)

Answer (score 2):

There's some stuff to comment on in your code, so I'll just go ahead and take the comments , the empty constructor and your input reading:

#### Comments:

> ```
> private String name;// contain the name of the job(optional)
> private int num;//contain the serial number of the job
> private int duration;// contain the processing time of the job
> private double start;//contain the starting time of the job
> private double end;//contain the ending time of the job
> ```

About everything in these comments can be dumped. the only thing that is useful here is `(optional)`. the rest is explicitly or implicitly given by code.

Instead something like this would have been enough:

```
private String name; //optional
private int serialNumber;
private int duration;
private double start;
private double end;
```

But let's stop here for a second and have an `<interjection>`:

`start` is a `double`, as well as `end`. Why in god's name is duration an `int` then?
And much more important, **what unit are you working in?** Days, Hours, Minutes, Weeks, Years, [...]?

`</interjection>`

Moving swiftly on:

> ```
> } // end of empty constructor
> ```

I personally strongly dislike this comment style, as it is a [code-smell](/questions/tagged/code-smell). There should not be a need to explicitly write into comments, which brace closes which block. If you need to do this, your code is too complex and **needs refactoring.** For a nice help on reducing indentation levels you might want to read through [Jeff's blogpost on "arrow code"](http://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/). To summarize in short: *extract functions and guard clauses.*

And on we go ;)

> ```
> //don't need to sort anymore! need to release memory for the calculation!!!
> sorter = null;
> ```

This is a quite **big** code-smell. While this may be true for low-level languages like [c](/questions/tagged/c) / [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) that is about useless in [java](/questions/tagged/java) Instead you should move the sorting to a separate method and let the garbage collector do that for you.

The GC is a very nice feature that allows you to just end a function without having to fear you got a memory leak (as long as you don't use `AutoClosable` resources, but we leave that aside for now). It collects and frees unused variables in the JVM for you, so you don't have to be bothered with `free variable` or `variable = null` and the like.

#### Empty Job Constructor:

What bothers me most about this piece of code is, that it's totally useless for the given assignment. Yea I know, from everywhere it shouts: "Implement the default constructor!" but IMO that's sometimes even counterproductive.

Instead you shouldn't allow instantiation of a job without values here. **How?** Just remove the constructor, and you're good to go ;)

**Why?** What sense does a job make, that has no serial number and no duration?

#### Reading Input From The User or: How To Write A Main-Method:

To make it short: Your main method is doing everything, and that in probably the most [i-am-new-to-programming](/questions/tagged/i-am-new-to-programming) possible way :(

[Here is another answer of mine,](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/49027/basic-postfix-calculator-in-java/49050#49050) that should show the general problem in your main method, as well as [one on parsing user input](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/46293/quadratic-expression-calculator/46298#46298)

I will sum these up here shortly either way:

Your main method is cramped with everything your program does. That's why it is so long and complicated and difficult to read. You should extract functionality out of your main-method into smaller parts. In the end your main method could read like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Job[] allJobs = readUserInput();
    Solution bestSolution = calculateSolution(allJobs);
    System.out.println(bestSolution.toString());
}
```

In one of the other answers I mentioned I have created a IMO very nice prompting method, which I slightly modified for here:

```
private String promptUserForInput(String prompt, Scanner in){
    System.out.println(prompt);
    return in.nextLine();
}
```

This is about the simplest way to extract the prompting into a method, if you want to keep it reusable.

Now to check for validity you'd need to do something like:

```
private int promptForNumberOfJobs () {
   String PROMPT = "Enter how many Jobs you have:";
   String userInput;
   int result;
   while (true) {
      userInput = promptUserForInput(PROMPT, new Scanner(System.In));
      try {
         result = Integer.parseInt(userInput);
         if(result >= 0){
            break;
         }
         else {
            System.out.println("The number of jobs must be 0 or larger");
         }
      } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
         System.out.println("Input is not a valid number.");
      }
   }
   return result;
}
```

I am confident you can get your code much more readable when following this advice, and I hope to see you again here on CodeReview, possibly with a follow up, as I haven't touched some aspects of your code that still need it :(